# How to reorder pages in a beamer handout?

Tags: beamer, positioning, handout

I would like to export the 8 slides of a Beamer presentation in 2 pages (4 slides per pages) in such a way that, when those pages are printed recto-verso, folded and cut, I get a "Scientific Comic book" of the presentation, to hand out to the audience. (I am starting with 8 to simplify, I would later like to scale to 3*8 = 24.)

Beamer handout is **almost** doing the trick, but one would need to put the slides in a distinct order to that after folding one does see the slide in the correct order (e.g. (n,1,n-1,2,n-2,3,...,n/2,n/2+1)). Hence my question: **can one specify in which order the slides appear in the beamer handout** (and how)?

I was almost sure that someone, somewhere, must have developed an entire package to make comics in LaTeX (there are package for music and many other things), but could not find any mention of any such package (using beamer or not). Maybe I am using the wrong words to describe what I am looking for (latex comic book brings many other types of results...)

Comment: Use a separate document with `pdfpages` to `\includepdf` the pages from the handout pdf. For simple cases, you can use `signature`. For more complex, you probably have to specify the order manually.

Comment: Err, sorry, maybe I should be more explicit. I am aware that one could reorder the slides in the original latex presentation, or separate the presentation pdf into separate files (on per page), create the pdf where they appear in a different order, and then create the corresponding handout with pdfnup. I am specifically asking if there is a way to do it directly in the parameters of beamer (and if there is a comics package that I missed out there).

Comment: You can try `pgfpages`. Although I find `pdfpages` easier by far. You seem to think there are far more steps involved in the latter than there are. You do need a second `.tex` file, but you certainly don't need to separate the pages into separate files or create a re-ordered PDF prior to creating the final handout. That is, you need two `.tex` files, but you don't need all the other files you mention. There is `booklet` but I can't say I would recommend it. It used to work, but I've given up on it for some time.

Comment: maybe go away from "doing this in TeX" and look at the printing capabilities of your pdf reader. Many have options to print booklets.